# Excel replace value with same amount of characters

Tags: microsoft-excel

We are using Excel reports which are visible to all employees. The idea is to replace each digit in the cell's value with the digit "1". They can have an indication of the value, i.e. hundreds or thousands, but not the exact amount.

Here's an example:

```
ORD          SUPPLY         RATE
3430         329961.25      95.07
```

should be converted to

```
ORD          SUPPLY         RATE
1111         111111.11      11.11
```

Is it possible, and how? I've tried replace and counting the number of digits to replace, etc. but couldn't get to a definite answer.

Comment: Do you need to do it with Find - Replace dialog, replacing numbers in the whole workbook / worksheet. Or you need a formula?

Comment: Whichever way can work, Its quite a large sheet (columns wise) so I suppose find - replace would be easiest, instead of having to apply formulas to each cell?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php; you can easily replace all numbers (`[0-9]`) to `1`

Comment: I have thought about doing something like **=REPLACE(E2,1,LEN(E2),1)** , which according to my understanding will repleace E2, starting at character 1 with X amount of 1's? But to no avail

Comment: "But to no avail" - what exactly went wrong?

Comment: Just gives me a Zero value, even if i take out the LEN() formula and put the num of chars in the actual cell, it ends up with 0

Comment: Strange you got `0`, it gives `1` for me. And both `=REPLACE(E2,1,LEN(E2),REPT(1,LEN(E2)))` and `=SUBSTITUTE(E2,E2,REPT(1,LEN(E2)))` works for me as you need.

Comment: Okay, i copied the data to another sheet and applied the formula again, which then worked. So I suppose it was formatting or something that "Zero'd" the result. Thank you for your assistance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to convert and run this short macro:

```
Option Explicit
Sub One_ification()
    Dim r As Range, v As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, CH As String

    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        L = Len(v)
        For i = 1 To L
            CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
            If CH Like "[0-9]" Then Mid(v, i, 1) = "1"
        Next i
        r.Value = v
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]